# Listen to Cursor onDrag movement android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to update a button text, only when the user drags the cursor handle in edittext. I have looked into onSelectionChanged(), but that doesn't resolve my issue. I have also overrided onTouchEvent() with custom editttext, but the drag event is not notified. Am i missing something? Is it possible to listen for cursor movement changes in edittext?

Comment: i think you need to listen if cursor (user touch) is on editText or not, yes ?

Comment: No, i need to listen to drag movement, when user drags the cursor in edittext.